# Getting valgrind errors with static char *

Tags: c, runtime-error, valgrind

I post because i'm really lost.
I've to do a function that reproduce the behavior of `getline`.

To do that, I have to create a `static` buffer that save the beginning of the next line for next calls. But making my buffer static generate some errors. I know that I can't `malloc` a `static char *`, and that I've to initialize only the first time. But I think the buffer is not really malloc when I recall the function, because I've some errors during the second and more calls. I put my code thereafter.

```
char *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *s_buffer = NULL;
    char *f_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
    static int read_size = 0;

    f_buffer[0] = '\0';
    if (!s_buffer) {
        s_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (READ_SIZE + 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < READ_SIZE + 1; i++)
            s_buffer[i] = '\0';
    }
    do {
        for (int i = 0; s_buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (s_buffer[i] == '\n') {
                s_buffer = my_substr(s_buffer, i + 1, READ_SIZE);
                return (f_buffer);
            }
            f_buffer = my_realloc(f_buffer, s_buffer[i]);
        }
        read_size = read(fd, s_buffer, READ_SIZE);
        if (read_size <= 0)
            return (NULL);
        s_buffer[read_size] = '\0';
    } while (1);
}
```

Functions `my_realloc` and `my_substr` are working, I tested them.

So first I get errors on `s_buffer[read_size] = '\0';`, invalid write.
And as I said before, I get some errors on the `read` function.

I put logs :

```
==2004== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==2004==    at 0x4F3B1B0: __read_nocancel (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so)
==2004==    by 0x4008D0: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:69)
==2004==    by 0x40094D: main (get_next_line.c:81)
==2004==  Address 0x5210ee6 is 0 bytes after a block of size 182 alloc'd
==2004==    at 0x4C2EB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==2004==    by 0x400747: my_substr (get_next_line.c:36)
==2004==    by 0x400862: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:64)
==2004==    by 0x40094D: main (get_next_line.c:81)
==2004==
==2004== Invalid write of size 1
==2004==    at 0x4008FA: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:72)
==2004==    by 0x40094D: main (get_next_line.c:81)
==2004==  Address 0x5210ef8 is 18 bytes after a block of size 182 alloc'd
==2004==    at 0x4C2EB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==2004==    by 0x400747: my_substr (get_next_line.c:36)
==2004==    by 0x400862: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:64)
==2004==    by 0x40094D: main (get_next_line.c:81)
```

I know that `Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)` means that my buffer is NULL, but it is not, i think.
However, I don't know for the invalid write.

If someone understand my code, I'm blocked since 3 days and I continue to not understand these errors.

Thanks for reading, bye ! (sorry for bad english)

Comment: I would really help to know which line as logged by Valgrind is where in the code you show.

Comment: What do `my_substr` do? What does it return? Is it correct to assign the result to `s_buffer`?

Comment: We probably need a [mcve] here.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `s_buffer = my_substr(s_buffer, ...` Why pass and assign to `s_buffer` if not for returning something different then passing in, which in turn leaked memory. Or should it be that `my_substr()` calls `realloc()`?

Comment: The "*write*" of 1 byte s "*invalid*" as it appears to write to "*18 bytes after a block of size 182 alloc'd*" in function `my_substr()` at line "*`get_next_line.c:36`*".

Comment: Wonder if that my_substr line is a typo and it should be assigning to the equally poorly named `f_buffer` since the next line it returns that.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, i solved my problem, it comes from my_substr, I didn't realloc my buffer correctly.